# A class that accepts two different data types in Java?

Tags: java, class

I want to make a class that can accept two different data types for each parameter. How can this be accomplished?

I realize the code below doesn't work, but how can I make something like that work? Basically so that parameter can be an int or String or something similar?

**Example:**

```
public Combat(int attack || String attack, int defence || String defence) {
        //code to parse strings into ints

    }
```

Comment: Write a method for each use case you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want to provide an [overloaded constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). You could delegate to the `int` version with something like,

```
private int attack;
private int defence;
public Combat(int attack, int defence) {
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defence = defence;
}
public Combat(String attack, String defence) {
    this(Integer.parseInt(attack), Integer.parseInt(defence));
}
```

if you wanted to pass `String, int` or `int, String` as well

```
public Combat(int attack, String defence) {
    this(attack, Integer.parseInt(defence));
}
public Combat(String attack, int defence) {
    this(Integer.parseInt(attack), defence);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was much easier than I would have ever imagined!

Answer (score 1):

You should create 2 constructors. I'll put an example below:

```
public Test(String test){
    // blah blah blah
}
public Test(int test){
    // blah blah blah
}
```

So when the instance is created, it can take either parameter.

Also, don't get confused with catch statements. Catches can take multiple exceptions with one |, example:

```
try{
    // blah blah blah
}
catch(TestException | TestExceptionTwo e){
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Using a single | doesn't work with constructors or methods.